# Apache Nifi - ConvertJSONToSQL - JSON Does not have a value for the required column

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to experiment with a tutorial I came across online, and here is its template:

[image]

While the template ended with converting CSV to JSON, i want to go ahead and dump this into a MySQL Table.
So i create a new processor "ConvertJSONToSQL".
Here are its properties:

[image]

And these are the controller services:

[image]

When i run this, i get the following error:

[image]

**Here is the sample input file:**

[image]

**Here is the MySQL Table Structure:**

[image]

Sample JSON Generated shown below:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "miss",
    "first": "marlene",
    "last": "shaw",
    "street": "3450 w belt line rd",
    "city": "abilene",
    "state": "florida",
    "zip": "31995",
    "gender": "F",
    "nationality": "US"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "ms",
    "first": "letitia",
    "last": "jordan",
    "street": "2974 mockingbird hill",
    "city": "irvine",
    "state": "new jersey",
    "zip": "64361",
    "gender": "F",
    "nationality": "US"
}]
```

I don't understand the error description. There is no field called "CURRENT_CONNECTIONS", would appreciate your inputs here please..

Comment: provide the structure of the table `USERS` and example of json

Comment: @daggett, edited the main post with the details pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you want to use the [PutDatabaseRecord processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/index.html) instead of ConvertJSONToSQL. This is because the output of *ConvertRecord - CSVtoJSON* is a record-oriented flow file (that is, a single flow file containing multiple records and a defined schema). ConvertJSONToSQL, from its [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertJSONToSQL/index.html), would expect a single JSON element:

> The incoming FlowFile is expected to be "flat" JSON message, meaning that it consists of a single JSON element and each field maps to a simple type

Record-oriented processors are designed to work together in a data flow that operates on structured data. They do require defining (or inferring) a schema for the data in your flowfiles, which is what the Controller Services are doing in your case, but the power is they allow you to encode/decode, operate on, and manipulate multiple records in a single flow file, which is much more efficient!

Additional resources that may be helpful:

- An introduction to effectively using the record-oriented processors together, such as ConvertRecord and PutDatabaseRecord: 
  https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi
- An example that includes PutDatabaseRecord: https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/b37db141b4d04c2da124c1a6d922f81f

Comment: Thank you @kevdoran, i will try this.